# how to change the culture of Kendo Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, culture, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to change the kendo Grid culture to nl-NL. . I have researched on internet and they suggest me that you just have to include the dll of that culture. . I have done that already and I have also referenced the same. I have also called that cuture using Kendo.Culture("nl-NL");
still not working

Comment: What is what you want to localize in Grid?

Comment: I want to filter menu plus No Items to Display message paging etc to be displayed accordingly current culture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have also set the server-side culture. A lot of info is available in the documentation: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/globalization